# Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой при запуске кода для телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

@bot.message_handler(commands= ['start'])
def say(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "hello world!")

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Вот сама ошибка

```
2022-10-29 17:54:28,707 (__init__.py:986 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
2022-10-29 17:54:28,707 (__init__.py:988 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 976, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 116,  in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 98, in run 
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 601, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1),
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 575, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 333, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 161, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 188, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized
```

Comment: Ошибка явно говорит о том, что не удалось авторизировать вашего бота. Ваш токен верный? А сам бот существует? Перепроверьте данные

Comment: проверю.заранее спасибо

Comment: Пересоздай токен или заново скопируй и вставь старый токен. Ошибка точно в нем

Answer (score 0):

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")
```

Запись "token" у тебя заменяет реальный токен?
Если да, то ошибка с токеном(401-ошибка авторизации)  Ты же обращался к FatherBot при создании бота?

Comment: нет.там мой токен

Comment: Я использовал aiogram, вместо телебота, и все было ок)